# Android app not able to open web link

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, browser

I have a button at the end of this app that takes the user to their default browser and to a predetermined link. Unfortunately, that button is broken. I am unsure of whether this is a problem with Java or with XML, but the code for both is attached.

```
package com.example.ldsm3;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Finished extends Activity {

    public void onClick(Button button1) 
    {

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("URL HERE"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finished);

        // tv is the ID for the TextView in the XML file
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 

        // set the TextView to show the score
        tv.setText(Misc.correct + "/" + Misc.total);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.finished, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the XML code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Finished" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:text="@string/Finished" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Go to the game!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
        android:text="0/0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this? Is it because of XML or Java? Did I not properly define the intent?

Comment: By `button is broken` you mean it's not doing anything?

Comment: Yes. However, the good news is that the app _isn't_ completely crashing.

Comment: You have the answer from Andrea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this on your `onCreate()` method:

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do your stuff here
  }
});
```