# Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener Java error

Tags: android, syntax, syntax-error

I'm creating an Android app and after my last question ([Android app not able to open web link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816809/android-app-not-able-to-open-web-link)), I've been getting this syntax error in Eclipse:

```
Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener
```

My code is as follows:

```
package com.example.ldsm3;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Finished extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finished);

        // tv is the ID for the TextView in the XML file
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 

        // set the TextView to show the score
        tv.setText(Misc.correct + "/" + Misc.total);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()); 

    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Open up the system's default browser to whackamole.ajav-games.tk, where the Whack A Mole game is.
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://whackamole.ajav-games.tk"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.finished, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? I know it is probably a simple Java error, but I have not used Java before, and please, when referring to Java syntax, terms, etc. explain them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this in place of `button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener());`

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO your code
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://whackamole.ajav-games.tk"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        };
    });
```

Comment: I'm curious about this question, not because I actually want to instantiate these, but because I want to learn more about anonymous inner classes in Java. It seems like the OnClickListener class was never meant to be instantiated outside of setOnClickListener. Are onClickListener objects not first-class citizens?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener());
```

to

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
});
```

and import `android.view.View.OnClickListener` then do whatever you want to do in `onClick` of the `onClickListener`

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
 public class Finished extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

`OnClickListener` is a interface and your class implements the interface

And have

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

because you already have

```
 public void onClick(View v)
```

and make sure you have the right import

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

OR using inner class. Annomymous inner class implements the interface

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
   Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://whackamole.ajav-games.tk"));
   startActivity(browserIntent);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`new Button.OnClickListener()`

is not how this is supposed to work. `OnClickListener` is an interface, so you have to implement it in a class and pass that class as the argument.

It seems you already implemented the method in your `Activity`, so:

- Add `implements View.OnClickListener` to your `Activity` declaration
- Set the `OnCLickListener`to the `Activity`:

  ```
  button1.setOnClickListener(this);
  ```

Comment: How do I do that? I do not thoroughly know Java.

Comment: Please read a book on Android programming to get yourself at least the basic knowledge.